# How to copy and paste on to next available row, with paste values?

Tags: excel, vba

newbie question! I'm sorry if it's a really obvious answer, just learning how to code effectively. I've been trying different codes to copy and paste data on to another excel workbook transposed, which is working. However it doesn't appear to be pasting values, nor can I get it to paste on to the next available row. I have found the commands but not sure in which order to insert them, and just seem to be getting errors.

This is my current working code, minus the command to paste on to the next available row:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Workbooks("CSA V0.3.xlsx").Worksheets("CSA - TL").Range("B2:B5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks("TL CSA Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Master").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Workbooks("CSA V0.3.xlsx").Worksheets("CSA - TL").Range("G9:G28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks("TL CSA Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Master").Range("E3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Where do I insert the code so that everytime the code is run, it pastes values on to the next available row? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the last used row first:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
With Workbooks("TL CSA Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Master")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in Column A

    Workbooks("CSA V0.3.xlsx").Worksheets("CSA - TL").Range("B2:B5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Workbooks("CSA V0.3.xlsx").Worksheets("CSA - TL").Range("G9:G28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, "E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End With
```

Or even better:

```
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = Workbooks("TL CSA Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Master")

Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Set wsSrc = Workbooks("CSA V0.3.xlsx").Worksheets("CSA - TL")

Dim NextFreeRow As Long
NextFreeRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find next free row in Column A

wsSrc.Range("B2:B5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(NextFreeRow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

wsSrc.Range("G9:G28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(NextFreeRow, "E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: I have another question... what if I now want it to skip a column whilst transposing? This is becoming more complicated! Sorry, and thanks in advance!

Comment: @SarahB Please ask a new question for that (and be much more detailed when describing), we cannot answer follow up questions in comments. • You will need to delete the column either before or after you copied it.